# alphanumeric with decimal(upto 3 places) regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for a field that can be letters or numbers and can enter decimal value up to 3 places

For number and decimal(up to three places ) i am using expression:-

`/^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,3})?\s*$/`

and for alphabets using `[\w]`,

For the letters and numbers with decimal I tried with expression:-

`/^[a-zA_Z0-9]?([.][0-9]){1,3}/`

but its not working.

For example:
It should pass bellow
"ABCD" or "121.213"

Not
"Abcd.121"

Comment: When you say "alphabets or numbers", do you mean one or the other at a time, or can you mix the two? E.g., is `"ABC123.456"` a valid value, or would it have to be either `"ABC"` or `"123.456"`? By the way, you don't mean "alphabets", you mean "letters". Please [edit] your question to show some sample valid and invalid values.

Comment: I edited the question , thank you for our reply

Answer (score 0):

In extended regex you can use the pipe character `|` to offer an option so a string like:

```
"/^([A-Za-z]+|[0-9.-]+)$/"
```

Will accept `ABC`, `123.12` but not `ABC123.456`

Comment: yes @nnnnnn, it would also accept things like `95.-2--.3` and won't accept characters like `éè'-` or unicode maybe needed. But the point was to present the `|` solution not build the exact regex